# Getting a "shell.js: internal error" when trying to release using TFS 2015 in a Windows Server 2012 R2 server

Tags: tfs

We've got a WPF application we're working on. We currently have two release environments to produce the WPF app, one is for Dev, the other is for Test. It is our practice to disable to automatic generation of a new release of Test release until later. There is only one release definition.

The Release definition is comprised of only three steps: Two are PowerShell++ scripts, written by the former TFS administrator, that changes the database connection string and signs the certificate for the WPF app (we use ClickOnce for deploying the app). The third step copies the files from the build location to the destination where the user can set the ClickOnce Setup.exe, when installing it, or where ClickOnce will retrieve new versions of the application when we do a build/release. Configuration variables define where the ClickOnce deployment is copied to. The copying of the files are to the same Windows Server 2012 R2 server, just different folders. The Test environmen released worked back in March when we last used it.

Today we needed to have a new Test version of the app produced, so I changed the deployment conditions on the Dev environment to allow for deployment after the release is created. Then I the release on both Dev and Test, using the latest build. It worked perfected for Dev, but it failed for Test. It failed on the last step. It failed with the following error:

> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z shell.js: internal error
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z Error: EPERM: operation not permitted,
> mkdir '\\ourserver\Releases\Pharmacy Warehouse\Pharmacy Warehouse
> Test' 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Error (native)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Object.fs.mkdirSync (fs.js:842:18)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at mkdirSyncRecursive
> (E:\agent2\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:11:8)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at
> E:\agent2\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:63:7
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Array.forEach (native)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Object._mkdir
> (E:\agent2\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\node_modules\shelljs\src\mkdir.js:48:8)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Object.mkdir
> (E:\agent2\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\node_modules\shelljs\src\common.js:186:23)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Object.mkdirP
> (E:\agent2\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\node_modules\vsts-task-lib\task.js:530:19)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Object.
> (E:\agent2\tasks\CopyFiles\1.0.13\copyfiles.js:167:8)
> 2020-09-18T16:13:20.2510464Z     at Module._compile (module.js:413:34)

I've never encountered this error before. When I've searched for it, I've found issues involving either npm or node.js. We're not using either npm or node.js for this WPF project. What is going on where shell.js is failing on the Test environment but works fine on the Dev environment?

Comment: Hi @Rod, could you set the variable system.debug to true and then share the full log here? In addition, please also try to update the agent and then try it again. Thanks

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, one of my colleagues was able to get the release to work. He checked in some changes, which launched the build/release sequence. At this point, because the release worked, I'm considering the issue closed.

Comment: Hi @VitoLiu-MSFT, like I said yesterday the issue is now past since my coworker was able to get the build to work. Nevertheless, I'd like to add that I have no idea at all where or how to set system.debug. I've never been given any training on TFS and am not likely to ever get it.

Comment: Hi @Rod, We can define the variable System.Debug and set it to true to get more detailed logs to debug pipeline issues, you can refer to this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/variables?view=azure-devops-2019&tabs=yaml#systemdebug) to get the detail info. By the way, could you please share the solution in the answer? In this case, others could directly find the useful solution. Thanks.